Dask KeyError when using pandas>=2.0.0
When using pandas==2.2.2 and trying to get dask dataframe column by index
from dask.dataframe import DataFrame
ddf = DataFrame.from_dict({"A": ["A|B", "C|D"]}, npartitions=2)["A"].str.partition("|")
print(ddf[1])

I get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\luabr\python\mnr-data-py-testing\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 413, in get_loc
    return self._range.index(new_key)
ValueError: 1 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  ...
  ...
  File "C:\Users\luabr\python\mnr-data-py-testing\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4102, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\luabr\python\mnr-data-py-testing\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 415, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1

However running the same code with pandas==1.5.3 I get the correct result
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=2
0    object
1       ...
1       ...
Name: 1, dtype: object
Dask Name: getitem, 4 graph layers

How to achieve compatibility between dask and pandas>=2.0.0 ?
Versions used:
dask==2024.5.1
pandas==2.2.2
python3.9.0


The issue arises from changes in how pandas handles the results of certain operations, particularly the str.partition method, between version 1.x and 2.x. This can cause compatibility issues with dask when attempting to access columns by index.
To address this, we can modify the approach to access the column in a way that is compatible with both pandas 2.x and dask. Specifically, instead of accessing the column by index, we can use the column name directly. After performing the str.partition operation, the columns are typically named (0, 1, 2) corresponding to the parts resulting from the partition.
from dask.dataframe import from_pandas
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["A|B", "C|D"]})

ddf = from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=2)

partitioned = ddf["A"].str.partition("|")

print(partitioned[1].compute())

